# 3 tables for 1 pivot

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Has anyone tried to make a pivot on 3 tables?

My case is a project management.

I have projects that contain multiple customers that contain multiple tasks.

I wish I could recover all cascaded

```
Project::with('customers')->with('customers.tasks')->get()
```

I have tried several times but nothing conclusive.

To give you an idea of the result: http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/01_basic.html

We have: Product launch (project) > Development (client) > Develop System (task)

Each task has a start date and an end date. So I have to be able to find these dates since the project itself (represented by the green bar).

If you have any ideas let me know :)

Comment: You might find hasManyThrough will help. It's hard to know exactly without seeing your full schema for those tables.

Comment: Can one customer have multiple projects?  Maybe it will help if you show your migrations.

Comment: My 3 tables (projects, customers, tasks) contain only an id and a name field except tasks which contains date_from and date_to.

Comment: Yes customers can have multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to create a pivot table between customers and tasks.  And it would also have a column for project_id.

This would give you the ability to find all of the customer's tasks and all tasks belonging to a certain customer.

Then you would have a projects table, and you'd be able to find a project's customers/tasks using hasManyThrough.  I believe this would also require you to setup a model for your customer_task table as well, but should be fairly straight forward.

Comment: "a pivot table between customers and tasks" = customer_id + task_id
If I add project_id it's like I did before

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it any easier, would I be wasting my time if I put together the models for this and some examples on how to use them?